# Speeding up for loops in Octave / matlab code

Tags: matlab, for-loop, octave, vectorization

It takes about 2 minutes to complete these loops does any know how I can speed this up / create the images faster other than changing the amount of colours or the amount of cells used? Would vectorization help at all and if so how should I do this?  Basically it creates a frame of an animation each loop

see code below

```
clear all,clf reset,tic,clc,clf

rgb1 = jet(256);
len1 = size(rgb1,1);
RGB1 = permute(rgb1,[3 1 2]);
figure; imshow(RGB1); %bar of colors
len2 = 200;

num2use=numel(num2str(length(rgb1)))+1 %count how many values and add 1. can use R also
lead_zeros=strcat('%0',num2str(num2use),'d'); %creates variable needed

for ii=0:length(rgb1)
  ii
  rgb1_shift=circshift(rgb1,[ii,:]);

  t = linspace(0,4*pi,len2);
  x = t.*cos(t);
  y = t.*sin(t);
  %rgb2 = interp1(1:len1,rgb1,linspace(1,len1,len2));
  rgb2 = interp1(1:len1,rgb1_shift,linspace(1,len1,len2));

  [xg,yg] = meshgrid([-t(end:-1:2) t],[-t(end:-1:2) t]);
  RGB2 = zeros([size(xg) 3]);
  % interpolate for the desired coordinates
  for c = 1:3
      RGB2(:,:,c) = griddata(x,y,rgb2(:,c),xg,yg);
  end
  imwrite(RGB2,strcat('/tmp/img2/',sprintf(lead_zeros, ii),'_spiral','.png')); %will create file without borders and use any resize in repmat

end


fprintf('\nfinally Done-elapsed time -%4.4fsec- or -%4.4fmins- or -%4.4fhours-\n',toc,toc/60,toc/3600);
```

Ps:  I'm using Octave 4.0 which is similar to matlab

Comment: You can move constants like `t = linspace(0,4*pi,len2);`,  and `[xg,yg] = meshgrid([-t(end:-1:2) t],[-t(end:-1:2) t]);` out of the loop. Measure time without `imwrite`, because it's I/O intensive. For the `griddata` method, Matlab gives a hint: "Consider replacing `griddata` with `scatteredinterpolant` for better performance". (missing in Octave).

Comment: use the Octave profiler to see where the bottleneck is. I doubt it is the for loop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few mistakes here which fixing them can improve the speed greatly:

1. Move all loop independent variable out of the loop.
   Namely move, `t = linspace(0,4*pi,len2);`, `x = t.*cos(t);`, `y = t.*sin(t);`, `[xg,yg] = meshgrid([-t(end:-1:2) t],[-t(end:-1:2) t]);` and `RGB2 = zeros([size(xg) 3]);` outside the loop.
2. Define `RGB2` directly by `RGB2(:) = cat(3, griddata(x,y,rgb2(:,1),xg,yg), griddata(x,y,rgb2(:,2),xg,yg), griddata(x,y,rgb2(:,3),xg,yg))` to avoid reallocation of the array in memory.

If you explain what exactly you're trying to of we might be even more helpful.

Comment: Basically it creates a frame of an animation each loop

Comment: What kind of animation? Could you show before and after?